# present NSString as a line of elements

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an NSString that hold data (actually that could be presented an NSArray). and i want to output that on a label.

In NSLog my NSString output is:

```
(
 "cristian_camino",
    "daddu_02",
    "_ukendt_babe_",
    "imurtaza.zoeb"
)
```

What i want is, to present it like :`"cristian_camino","daddu_02","_ukendt_babe_","imurtaza.zoeb"`

In a single line.

I could accomplish that turning string to an array and do following: `arrayObjectAtIndex.0, arrayObjectAtIndex.1, arrayObjectAtIndex.2, arrayObjectAtIndex.3.`

But thats look not good, and that objects may be nil, so i prefer NSString to hold data.

So, how could i write it in a single lane?

UPDATE:

There is the method i want to use to set text for UILabel:

```
-(void)setLikeLabelText:(UILabel*)label{

    //Likes

   NSString* likersCount = [self.photosDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"likes.count"];
   NSString* likersRecent = [self.photosDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"likes.data.username"];

    NSString *textString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - amount of people like it, recent "likes": %@", likersCount, likersRecent];

    label.text = textString;
    NSLog(@"text String is %@", textString);
}
```

Comment: 1. It looks like you already have an `NSArray` because what you show is how NSLog() would display an array. 2. The syntax you show for array elements is not Objective-C. 3. It looks like you are confused wrt strings and arrays and how NSLog displays things. 4. You need to show some code.

Comment: @Zaph please take a look at updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`valueForKeyPath:` returns an `NSArray`, not an `NSString`. Whilst you've declared `likersCount` and `likersRecent` as instances of `NSString`, they're actually both arrays of values. You should be able to do something like the following to construct a string:

```
NSArray* likersRecent = [self.photosDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"likes.data.username"];
NSString *joined = [likersRecent componentsJoinedByString:@"\", \""];
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", joined];
NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
```

`componentsJoinedByString:` will join the elements of the array with `", "`, and then the `stringWithFormat` call will add a `"` at the beginning and end.

Comment: Yes i know, actually i point at this in my question body. I want NSString with elements of NSArray object.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of how you might be able to do this.

Comment: Thank James, i agree, that is better approach.

Comment: When you say "componentsSeparatedByString: will join the elements of the array with..." Don't you mean to say that "componentsJoinedWithString: will join..."

Comment: If you know that valueForKeyPath returns an array, don't make the variable name of type NSString. That is a recipe for disaster. The fact that you typed likersCount and likersRecent as NSString indicates that you DON'T know and that you should pay careful attention to what James is telling you. You have some misconceptions and James is giving you good information on how to fix it. Read over his answer very carefully and go back and post updated code as an edit to indicate that you understand what he's telling you, or post follow-on questions.

Comment: The code you've posted creates arrays. The data you've shown IS arrays. You are confused.

Comment: @DuncanC yes i know, that is not good approach to treat NSArray like NSString.  And thank you, look like you care if i got this or not. I will read it again to understand what is James tried to tell me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The statement is incorrect, the internal quote marks (" that you want to display) need to be escaped:

```
NSString *textString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - amount of people like it, recent \"likes\": %@", likersCount, likersRecent];
```

Comment: Thank you but it still displayed in several lines, what i want is to display it in single line (without newline).

Answer (score 0):

If somebody curious how i fix it, there it is:

```
for (int i =0; i < [likersRecent count]; i++){


    stringOfLikers = [stringOfLikers stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@", [likersRecent objectAtIndex:i]]];
}
```

Not using commas or dots though.

Comment: You stated in your question that you wanted commas and quote marks (like "cristian_camino", "daddu_02", "_ukendt_babe_", "imurtaza.zoeb"), whereas your answer only inserts a space inbetween.